# Use app.all as oauth authorization middleware in node.js

Tags: node.js, express, oauth-2.0

I can't figure out how to use **app.all** to act as oauth authorization filter for all the routes starting with **/api/**

```
passport.authenticate('bearer', { session: false });
```

is used for authorization. and here are two standard get configurations:

```
app.get('/api/foo', foo.find);
app.get('/api/bar', bar.find);
```

I don't want to include it in every call like:

```
app.get('/api/foo', passport.authenticate('bearer', { session: false }), foo.find);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple, just get it to catch all routes starting with `api`. Make sure you put this **before** your routes.

```
app.all('/api/*', passport.authenticate('bearer', {session: false});
```